# Canon Printer Ink Life

Tags: printer

I have a '[Canon Pixma MG 2570S](https://www.google.co.in/aclk?sa=l&ai=CYFI_0M5KVti7CNiTogOtxofwA4fUj5wH17zd754Cx6D_zZwFCAYQBigIYOWq6YPkDqAB-bWDygPIAQepAtKar2URSVA-qgQlT9DMlWB3-7imYEvOdyzillQhAiGO2Es4b_2t7dQ0vyUX5m-a-sAFBaAGJoAH78n8NZAHAagHpr4b2AcB4BK-1J2o6PLFuKMB&sig=AOD64_25Oxsqlwvr_UsjvnuIUmyG8HKjdQ&ctype=5&clui=13&q=&ved=0CJABELsXahUKEwiFqdfR75bJAhVHkY4KHcBHBIo&adurl=http://tracking-in.sokrati.com/click%3Fclient_id%3D432%26tag%3Dg-1z2z2zn3z12qwyyh_432%26svt%3D1%7C%7C%7Cg%7C%7C76942987447%7C1o6%7C%26redirect_url%3Dhttp://rover.ebay.in/rover/1/4686-187859-10941-22/2%3F%26site%3DPartnership_PLA%26mpre%3Dhttp://www.ebay.in/itm/like/111814299851%253Faff_source%253DSok-Goog)' Priner. I use this printer rarely. Kindly let me know that for how many days the ink will remain unaffected ?

Comment: Epson's inks are good for 6 months after opening; can't say for Canon.

Comment: Did you read the manual ? It must say that

Answer (score 0):

That's difficult to say as it strongly depends on the humidity percentage and temperature of the room where the printer is stored.

In general, a big problem of inkjet printers is that the ink in the cartridges dries out if not used, and this clogs the nozzle.  To avoid this problem, you should print something in colour at least twice a month.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a printer technician, and I can say...

If not used, the ink can stay inside the ink cartridge for about 1 year. I recommend closing all the doors in the printer, up and down.

Like the first answer says, it depends on the humidity and temperature. This means you can help by closing all the doors.

The other thing I recommend  is to print, once a week, once a month is too long a time, using all the colors when you print something.

What to do when using a printer for the first after it has been stored for a long time: http://www.en.rellenadodecartuchos.com/2015/06/what-to-do-for-used-printer-after-long-time-stored.html